# NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS in SQL loader control file

Tags: oracle-11g, sql-loader

I am using a Control File to import data from a CSV file into a table, using sqlldr to import the data, where a large number of fields are numeric values with integer and decimal part separated by dots. 
The Control File works just fine because I cast the number to the input my table expects by using

```
"TO_NUMBER(:MyVariable, '9999999999D999999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''.,''')"
```

Although the control file works just fine I would like to know: Is it possible to use:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ","
```

In this way I don't mind about differences between character used in NLS and the one used to create the file, nor i mind about the actual number of decimal significative number.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question and I find a solution that works for me!

You have to put the sentence `set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=,.` in the beginning of the .bat file. This must be before you call the load in the .ctl file.